# ConEmu opens several tabs on Win+W (Create new console button)

Tags: tabs, conemu

ConEmu opens several tabs on Win+W (Create new console button).

Suppose I have two tabs already opened:

[image]

When I press the green plus button to create a new console tab, I do not get just one new console tab. Instead, my already opened tabs get duplicated. I end up with four tabs instead of the expected three tabs (two already opened and one newly created).

Note: I have a setting to "Auto save/restore opened tabs" on Startup enabled.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How do you think, what ConEmu shall do on green-plus-button click?

Comment: ConEmu shall open a new console tab of whatever type is set as default. Is not it?